# How to implement search like Stack Overflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have implemented the full text search using [Sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29) and [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/).
I want to add  column wise search.  Some thing like:-(taking an example of Stack Overflow)

Suppose you want to see actvities related to you, just type:

```
  user:me
```

Then it will return a result with all the questions and answers related to piemesons.

If you type

```
 votes:15
```

then it will return a result with all the questions tagged with having more than 15 votes.

And if you type

```
  user:me votes:15
```

then it will return all the questions and answers belonging to you with more than 15 votes.

How can I implement  this thing?

Right now my search results are based upon full text search. How can these kinds of features be included?

Any options avaliable in Sphinx or [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) or any other search engines?

Answer (score 2):

`:with` option in thinking sphinx.

First of all, you have to define those attributes in your index definition ([check out attributes section here](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/indexing.html)).

```
has views_count, :as => :views, :type => :integer
has user.id, :as => :user, :type => :integer
```

Then you could search for posts like this:

```
Post.search '', :with => {:views => 12..maxint, :user => User.first.id}
```

(I am not sure if there is any more elegant possibility of giving open ranges, but 12..max_int should be enough)

Two important things:

1. if you want to count related objects (e.g. responses), you should use counter cache
2. if your "user" is polymorphic association, I recommend `"CRC32(CONCAT(user_type, user_id))"` instead of `user.id`